# Problems combining JWT Bearer Authenticating Web API with Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following setup:

Web API with JWT Bearer Auth

Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC handling identities and providing views

AngularJS - client

Angular is requesting JWT token and passing it on subsequents http requests.
AJAX calls are working fine. The problem is if I request an MVC action with [Authorize] through my browser, that token is obviously not validated, because there is no cookie and no auth header.

How would I go about implementing signin functionality to non-ajax requests?

I assume I need to implement some sort of Cookie Authentication, but I was hoping to avoid it after moving to JWT.

I know this could probably be solved by migrating to SPA, but I was wondering if there was a way to keep todays solution with MVC serving views - old habit :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want server-side JWT authentication, then you need to store your JWT in a cookie instead of local storage. Cookies are issued for your site's domain, so when you request youre MVC app for a view and assuming your API and your MVC site have the same origin (same schema + host + port), there should be no problem for protected MVC controller to process incoming cookie in HTTP(S) request and make a decision on how to respond. WebAPI should also be able to handle cookies with JWT payload. I found nice article with sample project about ASP.NET Core MVC Authentication here: https://auth0.com/blog/asp-dot-net-core-authentication-tutorial/
For your AngularJS SPA it shouldn't be a problem to set JWT to a cookie instead of putting it to local storage. It would be actually more secure way to store JWT, but you need to make sure your JWT won't get too long, because cookie payload size is limited. More about it here: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage